# Bash script, if statement in while loop, unwanted duplicate output

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, while-loop, m3u

I'm doing a script to parse m3u files.
The goal is to retrieve the variable tag and the url.
I tested with [this file.](https://iptv-org.github.io/iptv/countries/fr.m3u)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "name,tvg-id,tvg-name,tvg-country,group-title,languages,url"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    tags_detect="$(echo "$line" | grep -Eo '^#EXTINF:')"

    if [[ -n ${tag_detect} ]]; then
        get_chno="$(echo "$line" | grep -o 'tvg-chno="[^"]*' | cut -d '"' -f2)"
        get_id="$(echo "$line" | grep -o 'tvg-id="[^"]*' | cut -d '"' -f2)"
        get_logo="$(echo "$line" | grep -o 'tvg-logo="[^"]*' | cut -d '"' -f2)"
        get_grp_title="$(echo "$line" | grep -o 'group-title="[^"]*' | cut -d '"' -f2)"
        get_title="$(echo "$line" | grep -o ',[^*]*' | cut -d ',' -f2)"
        get_tvg_name="$(echo "$line" | grep -o 'tvg-name="[^"]*' | cut -d '"' -f2)"
        get_country="$(echo "$line" | grep -o 'tvg-country="[^"]*' | cut -d '"' -f2)"
        get_language="$(echo "$line" | grep -o 'tvg-language="[^"]*' | cut -d '"' -f2)"

        phrase="${get_title},${get_id},${get_tvg_name},${get_country},${get_grp_title},${get_language}"
    else
        url="$line"

    fi
    echo "${phrase},${url}"

done <"${1}"
```

So, Without "If" it works but i don't have url.
I add a "IF" and ... :

```
,#EXTM3U
4 Turk Music,4TurkMusic.fr,4 Turk Music,FR;TK,Music,Turkish,#EXTM3U
4 Turk Music,4TurkMusic.fr,4 Turk Music,FR;TK,Music,Turkish,http://51.210.199.30/hls/stream.m3u8
Alpe d’Huez TV,AlpedHuezTV.fr,Alpe d’Huez TV,FR,,French,http://51.210.199.30/hls/stream.m3u8
Alpe d’Huez TV,AlpedHuezTV.fr,Alpe d’Huez TV,FR,,French,https://edge10.vedge.infomaniak.com/livecast/ik:adhtv/chunklist.m3u8
```

... It's broken and I don't found my error.

desired output:

```
4 Turk Music,4TurkMusic.fr,4 Turk Music,FR;TK,Music,Turkish,http://1.2.3.4/hls/stream.m3u8
Alpe d’Huez TV,AlpedHuezTV.fr,Alpe d’Huez TV,FR,,French,https://edge10.vedge.infomaniak.com/livecast/ik:adhtv/chunklist.m3u8
```

I don't understand my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's broken and I don't found my error.

Paste you script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

---

Here is how I would do it in bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf '%s\n' "name,tvg-id,tvg-name,tvg-country,group-title,languages,url"

while IFS= read -r data; do
  [[ $data != '#EXTINF:-1'* ]] && continue
  IFS= read -r url && [[ $url != 'http'* ]] && echo "$url" && continue
  if [[ "$data" == '#EXTINF:-1'* && "$url" == 'http'* ]]; then
    title=${data#*\",}
    tvg_id=${data#*tvg-id=\"} tvg_id=${tvg_id%%\"*}
    tvg_name=${data#*tvg-name=\"} tvg_name=${tvg_name%%\"*}
    tvg_country=${data#*tvg-country=\"} tvg_country=${tvg_country%%\"*}
    group_title=${data#*group-title=\"} group_title=${group_title%%\",*}
    tvg_language=${data#*tvg-language=\"} tvg_language=${tvg_language%%\"*}
    printf '%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n' "$title" "$tvg_id" "$tvg_name" "$tvg_country" "$group_title" "$tvg_language" "$url"
  fi
done < file.txt
```

Although I'm not sure what should happen at line 233 and 238 those lines starts with `#EXTVLCOPT`

---

An `ed` solution if available/acceptable.

The script, name it anything you like. I'll just name it `script.ed`

```
g/^#EXTINF:-1/s/$/ /\
;/^http\(s\)\{0,1\}.*/-1;/^[^#]*$/j
,s/^#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="\([^"]*\)" tvg-name="\([^"]*\)" tvg-country="\([^"]*\)" tvg-language="\([^"]*\).* group-title="\([^"]*\)",\(.*\) \(http.*\)\{0,1\}/\6,\1,\2,\3,\5,\4,\7/
1c
name,tvg-id,tvg-name,tvg-country,group-title,languages,url
.
,p
Q
```

---

Now run it against the file in question.

```
ed -s file.txt < script.ed
```

- Remove the `,p` from the script to silence the output to stdout or if you're satisfied with the output.
- Change `Q` to `w` from the script if *in-place* editing is needed.

---

Should give more or less same result as the bash solution, but since  it is still unknown what should happen at line 233 and 238 those lines starts with `#EXTVLCOPT`

Comment: Thank you very much, I 'm already using Shellcheck, and I had no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You probably better use a more capable language like [Perl](https://www.perl.org/).

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "name,tvg-id,tvg-name,tvg-country,group-title,languages,url\n";

my %tags;
my $title;

while (<>)
{
  next if /^#EXTM3U/;
  if (s/^#EXTINF:-1//) {
    %tags = ();
    $tags{$1} = $2 while (s/\s*(\S+)="([^"]*)"//);
    ($title) = $_ =~ /,(.*)/;
  } else {
    print join (',', $title,
                $tags{'tvg-id'},
                $tags{'tvg-name'},
                $tags{'tvg-country'},
                $tags{'group-title'},
                $tags{'tvg-language'},
                $_);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick refactor (untested) -

```
declare -A tag
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case "$line" in
    \#EXTINF:*) 
      if [[ "$line" =~ ,([^*]+) && -n "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}" ]]; then
        tag[title]="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
        phrase="${tag[title]}"
      fi
      for id in tvg-id tvg-name tvg-country group-title tvg-language tvg-chno tvg-logo; do
        pat=$id'="([^"]+)"'
        [[ "$line" =~ $pat ]] && tag[$id]="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}";
        phrase="$phrase,${tag[$id]}"
      done
      phrase="${phrase%,${tag[tvg-chno]},${tag[tvg-logo]}}"
    ;;
    *) url="$line"
    esac
    echo "${phrase},${url}"
done <"${1}"
```

Needs a lot more error checking...

Comment: Thank you, but is the same effect. It's so weird.